# In Docusign: What is the usage of DocumentId and ReceipentId?

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am creating envelope to be send to docusign in which I need to set few parameters as mentioned below:

```java
Document doc = new Document();  
String base64Doc = fileBytes;
doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
doc.setName("Demo File.pdf"); // can be different from actual file name
doc.setDocumentId("1");

List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();//arraylist
docs.add(doc);
envDef.setDocuments(docs);

Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.setEmail("kkk@kkk.com");
signer.setName("K");
signer.setRecipientId("1");
```

I am having doubts about these 2 API methods:

1. `setDocumentId("1");`

   **Question 1**: What are the valid values I can set here?
   **Question 2**: What is the use of it?
2. `setRecipientId("1");`

   **Question 1**: What are the valid values I can set here?
   **Question 2**: What is the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

The two ids are used to identify the document(s) and recipient(s) within the context of the envelope request.

**Re what are the valid values?**

I recommend that you use integer values. You can probably use non-integers if you want, I don't know for sure.

Eg, Id the first document as `1`, the second as `2`. Same for the recipients.

**Re How are they used?**

You "set" a document's id in the `documents` section of the create call. You "set" the recipient ids in the `recipients` section.

Then you use them in the `tabs` section of the create call.

See the [multiple docs recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/send-multiple-docs) for an example.

Comment: Thank you Larry for your kind info, let me check suggested link and will revert once it looks ok to me.